# Vectors to find Median - homework

Tags: c++

I'm a relatively new learner to C++ and I've been having some trouble. If you guys read the title, this is a homework problem (just letting you guys know out there) and I'm not really sure as to where my error is. Using GIT Bash, I can't see why this isn't compiling (or maybe i just don't know how to read it). I feel like i've touched upon all the bases and would appreciate a quick look over to see if my mistake is blaringly obvious. I've done a couple looks through stackoverflow and so the inputting values into a vector was used from another post but i've modified it a bit. In addition, I added in a sort for the vector from smallest to largest.

Also, how can I change the for statement to allow for variable #'s in the vector?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


double showMedian(const vector<int> & vecmedian, int size)
{
int middle;
double average, median;

middle = size / 2.0;

if (size % 2 == 0)
    {
    median = (vecmedian[middle] + vecmedian[middle + 1]) / 2.0;
    cout << "The median is: " << average << endl;
    }
else
    {
    median = vecmedian[middle + 0] / 1.0;

    cout << "The median is: " << median << endl;
    }
return median;
}

int main()
{
int n,input, i;
vector<int> vecmedian;
vector<int>::iterator itr;
cout << "Enter the amount of numbers: ";
cin >> n;
cout << "Enter your numbers to be evaluated: " << endl;
while (vecmedian.size() < n && cin >> input){
vecmedian.push_back(input);
}
for(i = 1;  i < 10;  ++i){
  for(itr = vecmedian.begin();  itr != vecmedian.end();  ++itr){
     if(vecmedian[i] < *itr){
    vecmedian.insert(itr, vecmedian[i]);
    break;
 }
  }
  if(itr == vecmedian.end())
     vecmedian.push_back(vecmedian[i]);
}   
showMedian();
return 0;

}
```

Comment: You forgot to tell us what the error is.

Comment: It would be helpful if you added the compiler output you're seeing. Also, you're using an array? called `nums` but you haven't actually declared or populated it anywhere. Perhaps you mean `vecmedian`?

Comment: I notice showMedian is declared with no parameters and then later declared with parameters.

Comment: @NeilKirk the thing is, when I try to compile it, the program just closes on me. I've restarted the computer a few times and I've tried different computers, but that's the problem i get. I declared showMedian at the bottom...? Do you mean that i should move it to the top?
My bad, I copy and pasted from my notepad instead of my compiler so there were still some errors on the notepad that were fixed on my compiler and that was one of them.

Comment: @uanaka, you have a lot of compiler errors.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't compile. http://ideone.com/Oe6MiY

Comment: @NeilKirk the above should be able to compile now, however after entering said # of integers, nothing happens after that. Any ideals?

Comment: What is the loop `for(i = 1;  i < 10;  ++i)` for?

Comment: The loop is supposed to help me sort the numbers from least to greatest, but i'm not sure how to do it without specifying a certain amount of numbers? would i < n work?

Answer (score 2):

**Point 1**

When making `function prototypes`, you need to keep them consistent with the actual definition of the `function`.

You have:

```
void showMedian();
```

As a `function-prototype` but you have:

```
double showMedian(int *vecmedian, int size)
```

As the actual definition. **They both need to be consistent**.

Since you have not declared an array, maybe change the parameters of `showMedian` to:

```
double showMedian(const vector<int> & vecmedian, int size)
```

**Point 2**

```
if(nums[i] < *itr)
```

Where is `nums` declared?

**Point 3**

If you want to use the definition of `showMedian`, then use the parameters that it uses assuming you made the changes above (and assuming `n` is size).

```
showMedian(vecmedian, n);
```

**Edit**

With all the consulting in the comment section and the new updated OP Question, here is a fairly solid program which finds the `median` in a `vector`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

double showMedian(const vector<double> & vecmedian, int num);

int main()
{
    unsigned int n;
    double input;
    vector<double> vecmedian;

    // cout << "Enter the amount of numbers: ";

    do {
        cout << "Enter the amount of numbers: ";

        while(!(cin >> n)){
            cout << "Wrong input" << endl;
            cout << "Enter the amount of numbers: ";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }

        if (n == 0)
        {
            cout << "Invalid, size must be greater than 0" << endl;
        }

    } while (n == 0);

    // cout << "Enter your numbers to be evaluated: " << endl;

    for (int i  = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        cout << "Enter number here (" << ((n + 1) - i) << " number/s remaining): ";
        while(!(cin >> input)){
            cout << "Wrong input" << endl;
            cout << "Enter number here (" << ((n + 1) - i) << " number/s remaining): ";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }

        vecmedian.push_back(input);
    }

    //        while (vecmedian.size() < n && cin >> input){
    //            vecmedian.push_back(input);
    //        }

    sort(vecmedian.begin(), vecmedian.end());

    showMedian(vecmedian, vecmedian.size());
    return 0;

}

double showMedian(const vector<double> & vecmedian, int num)
{
    int middle;
    double median;

    middle = (num / 2);
    if (num % 2)
        median = vecmedian[middle];
    else
        median = (vecmedian[middle - 1] + vecmedian[middle]) / 2.0;
    cout << "The median is: " << median << endl;
    return median;
}
```

Comment: @Hayden thanks for the help! You've really helped to simplify it, but I was wondering how that sorting function worked? Also, what's the trigger to move on to the next part after you enter in the #'s? The way i'm entering numbers is say, I write that i want to evaluate 4 numbers, then i'll type, 8642 and then enter. but nothing.

Comment: Internally, the sorting function uses `quicksort` I believed which is a very fast sorting algorithm. Your sorting algorithm had a bug which entered numbers to the vector when it shouldn't so I replaced it with this one, as it is much more robust. You have to enter things like so: enter the amount is numbers (e.g. 5) > press enter; enter first number > enter; second number > enter; etc.

Comment: If you want to know how the sort function works, visit here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

Comment: I've tried that, but it doesn't continue on. It might be the compiler i'm using, but it just doesn't move onto the median part

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: "Enter the amount of numbers: " for this instance I will type **4**.

Comment: if the input loop breaks early, then `n` and `vec.size()` will be different, but you still use `n` for the calculation. Dont send `n` to the function, use `.size()` instead.

Comment: I then type:   1 > enter > 3 > enter > 2 > enter > 4 > enter.

Comment: Good suggestion sp2danny

Comment: Yea, it breaks and doesn't do the whole declaring the median cout. @sp2danny could you elaborate a bit more on what you mean?

Comment: He means that if it does break, then use vecmedian.size() rather than n as the size parameter in showMedian, I updated my answer for it.

Comment: Try the code above, otherwise use this: ideone.com/